# Issue with Retrieving Job Parameters Using Spring Expression Language in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am working with a Spring Batch application, where I call jobLauncher from my controller and pass job parameters to it. However, I'm encountering an issue when trying to retrieve these parameters using Spring Expression Language (SpEL). The error message indicates that the job parameters are not found.

Error that I am facing:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-11-23 23:02:56.008 ERROR 3224 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'LCCUtilController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'job'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'readCSVFilesJob' defined in class path resource [com/accelya/revera/order/lcc/processing/BatchProcessing.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'readCSVFilesJob' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) [spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) [spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at com.accelya.revera.order.LCCBatchProcessingApplication.main(LCCBatchProcessingApplication.java:30) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'readCSVFilesJob' defined in class path resource [com/accelya/revera/order/lcc/processing/BatchProcessing.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'readCSVFilesJob' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:170) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1631) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:91) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:55) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:91) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:273) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:167) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Controller Class:

```
@GetMapping("/start")
    public APITransferObject startBatchJob(@RequestParam String filePath)
    {
        APITransferObject apiTransferObject = new APITransferObject();
        try
        {
            JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addString("filePath", filePath)
                    .addLong(LCCBatchProcessingConstants.PROCESS_CONFIGURATION.TIME.getValue(), System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
            BatchStatus batchStatus = execution.getStatus();
            if (batchStatus == BatchStatus.COMPLETED)
            {
                apiTransferObject.setSuccess(true);
                apiTransferObject.setData(LCCBatchProcessingConstants.EXECUTION_STATUS.COMPLETED_SUCCESSFULLY.getValue());
                return apiTransferObject;
            }
            else if (batchStatus == BatchStatus.FAILED)
            {
                apiTransferObject.setSuccess(false);
                apiTransferObject.setData(LCCBatchProcessingConstants.EXECUTION_STATUS.ERROR.getValue());
                return apiTransferObject;
            }
            else
            {
                apiTransferObject.setSuccess(true);
                apiTransferObject.setData(LCCBatchProcessingConstants.EXECUTION_STATUS.STARTED.getValue().concat(batchStatus.getBatchStatus().toString()));
                return apiTransferObject;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            commonLoggingUtil.error(LCCBatchProcessingConstants.EXECUTION_STATUS.ERROR.getValue(), e);
            apiTransferObject.setSuccess(false);
            apiTransferObject.setData(LCCBatchProcessingConstants.EXECUTION_STATUS.ERROR.getValue());
            return apiTransferObject;
        }
    }
```

Configuration Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchProcessing
{
    @Autowired
    private DataSource          datasource;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory   jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory  stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private CommonLoggingUtil   commonLoggingUtil;


    @Value(value = "${batchProcessing.filePattern}")
    private String              filePattern;

    /**
     * It initializes the logger for the `BatchProcessing` class.
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void initLogger()
    {
        commonLoggingUtil.setLOGGER(BatchProcessing.class);
    }

    /**
     * Configures and returns a Spring Batch job named "readCSVFilesJob" for processing CSV files. This job uses a RunIdIncrementer for generating unique job instances and starts with the "processNvBooking".
     *
     * @return Configured Spring Batch job.
     */
    @Bean                      
    public Job readCSVFilesJob(@Value("#{jobParameters['filePath']}") String filePath)
    {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get(LCCBatchProcessingConstants.JOBS.READ_CSV_FILES_JOB.getValue())
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(processNvBooking(filePath))
        .build();
    }

    /**
     * * Configures and returns a Spring Batch step named "processNvBooking" for processing chunks of CSV data. The step uses a reader to read data, a processor to process it, and a writer to write to the database.
     *
     * @return Configured Spring Batch step.
     */

    @Bean                       
    public Step processNvBooking(@Value("#{jobParameters['filePath']}") String filePath)
    {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get(LCCBatchProcessingConstants.STEPS.PROCESS_NV_BOOKING.getValue())
        .<NvBooking, NvBooking> chunk(5)
        .reader(multiResourceItemReader(filePath))
        .writer(writer())
        .build();
    }

    /**
     * * Configures and returns a Spring Batch multi-resource item reader that reads from multiple CSV files.
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public MultiResourceItemReader<NvBooking> multiResourceItemReader(String filePath)
    {
        Resource[] inputResources = null;
        ResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();

        try
        {
            inputResources = patternResolver.getResources(LCCBatchProcessingConstants.PROCESS_CONFIGURATION.FILE.getValue().concat(filePath).concat(filePattern));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            commonLoggingUtil.error("Error while Reading from the source path: ", e);
        }

        MultiResourceItemReader<NvBooking> resourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<NvBooking>();
        resourceItemReader.setStrict(false);
        resourceItemReader.setResources(inputResources);
        resourceItemReader.setDelegate(reader());
        return resourceItemReader;
    }

    /**
     * Configures and returns a Spring Batch flat file item reader for reading CSV data. The reader uses UTF-16 encoding and a line mapper with a delimited line tokenizer to map CSV fields to `NvBooking` properties.
     *
     * @return Configured Spring Batch flat file item reader.
     */
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<NvBooking> reader()
    {
        FlatFileItemReader<NvBooking> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<NvBooking>();

        reader.setEncoding(LCCBatchProcessingConstants.PROCESS_CONFIGURATION.ENCODING.getValue());
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<NvBooking>()
        {
            {
                setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer()
                {
                    {
                        setNames(Arrays.stream(NV_BOOKING_FIELD.values()).map(NV_BOOKING_FIELD::getValue).toArray(String[]::new));
                        setDelimiter(LCCBatchProcessingConstants.PROCESS_CONFIGURATION.DELIMITER.getValue());

                    }
                });
                setFieldSetMapper(new NvBookingFieldSetMapper());
            }
        });
        return reader;
    }

    /**
     * Configures and returns a Spring Batch JDBC item writer for writing `NvBooking` objects to the database.
     *
     * @return Configured Spring Batch JDBC item writer.
     */

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<NvBooking> writer()
    {
        return new JdbcItemWriter<NvBooking>(datasource);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the bean `processNvBooking` is not scoped. A bean should be step-scoped or job-scoped for the late binding of attributes with a SpEL expression to work. This is mentioned in the documentation here: [Late Binding of Job and Step Attributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/step/late-binding.html)

You can mark the step as job-scoped:

```
@Bean    
@JobScope                   
public Step processNvBooking(@Value("#{jobParameters['filePath']}") String filePath) {
     return stepBuilderFactory.get(LCCBatchProcessingConstants.STEPS.PROCESS_NV_BOOKING.getValue())
        .<NvBooking, NvBooking> chunk(5)
        .reader(multiResourceItemReader(filePath))
        .writer(writer())
        .build();
    }
```

Or move the scope to the component that needs it, which is the reader in your case:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public MultiResourceItemReader<NvBooking> multiResourceItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['filePath']}") String filePath) {
    Resource[] inputResources = null;
    ResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();

    try {
            inputResources = patternResolver.getResources(LCCBatchProcessingConstants.PROCESS_CONFIGURATION.FILE.getValue().concat(filePath).concat(filePattern));
     } catch (IOException e) {
         commonLoggingUtil.error("Error while Reading from the source path: ", e);
     }

     MultiResourceItemReader<NvBooking> resourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<NvBooking>();
     resourceItemReader.setStrict(false);
     resourceItemReader.setResources(inputResources);
     resourceItemReader.setDelegate(reader());
     return resourceItemReader;
    }
```

In this case, you can pass `null` to the method in the step definition like `.reader(multiResourceItemReader(null))`, but I don't recommend that. The recommended way is to pass dependencies through the parameters of the step bean definition method, like:

```
@Bean                       
public Step processNvBooking(MultiResourceItemReader<NvBooking> multiResourceItemReader, JdbcBatchItemWriter<NvBooking> writer) {
     return stepBuilderFactory.get(LCCBatchProcessingConstants.STEPS.PROCESS_NV_BOOKING.getValue())
        .<NvBooking, NvBooking> chunk(5)
        .reader(multiResourceItemReader)
        .writer(writer)
        .build();
    }
```